# Talend - How to choose delimiter when CSV record occupy multiple lines

Tags: talend

I have a **CSV** file that contains many records. One record has a column named Objective, it of type text : paragraphs, line break, etc.

I try to display the content of the file with **tLog**  component and **tInputFileDelimiter**.

My problem :
By using "\n" as delimiter of the CSV record, I have **memory heap problem**. Because, one record can be considered as 20 records.

Comment: Could you put another character instead of \n as delimiter ? As if you have \n in your Objective column, Talend won't be able to know if it is a mark of a new line or a data of this column. Another solution would be to generate the CSV file with a Text Delimiter like " " , to surround the value of the Objective column.

Comment: You may refer to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43583532/talend-newline-character-in-middle-of-csv-column/43700841#43700841